# Using STL classes without including their appropriate headers

Tags: c++, header, include, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>

struct S { };

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    // Do whatever work I need to with v

    // Oh, by the way, I also need std::allocator for something else...
    std::allocator<S> a;
    S s;
    a.construct(&s, S());
    a.destroy(&s);
}
```

`std::allocator` is declared in `<memory>`, but I have *not* included that header.

Questions:

1. Can I still rely on `std::allocator` being fully usable through the inclusion of `<vector>`? Why/why not?
2. If so, what *other* classes can I rely on being included indirectly, and under what conditions?
   (Is there a list somewhere, or would I have to figure them out manually?)
3. Is it good practice to avoid including the specific header (e.g. `<memory>`) if you've already included another header that implies the inclusion of the class you need? Why/why not?

Comment: The standard lists a few of these, but I don't know where.

Comment: I'd say "not good practice" in a general sense, as what works on one compiler might fail on another.  I saw that happen earlier today with a missing overload on `<<`.  On one compiler, including `iostream` was enough to get an overload that would print a `string`; another compiler needed `<string>` to make it work.

Comment: It's always best to include the files you know you need.  There's no guarantee that something else will always be included.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: No guarantee? How can this code possibly fail?

Comment: Perhaps it can't for your contrived example, but let's say compiler version x includes `string` when you include `iostream`, but compiler version y does not.  If you are interested in making your code portable and maintainable then you should always include what you need.

Comment: @JoeZ: `iostream` and `string` are different beasts, though. I think the problem there is the fact that `<<` is a nonmember function, and nothing inside `iostream` really *needs* the definition of that function either. Over here, everything is a member function, and I since everything is template-based, I don't see how `vector` can possibly be defined without also implying `std::allocator::construct` has been defined.

Comment: In other words, I know it's easy to find examples where it's *not* guaranteed to work, but are there examples in which it *is* guaranteed to work? If so, is it good practice to rely on this guarantee? If not, why not? etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad, Here's one concerning `std::begin` and `std::end`: C++11 § 24.7

Comment: @chris: I don't have the official standard unfortunately. I have the N3242 draft but that doesn't go beyond 24.6...

Comment: @Mehrdad, Ah, well that was referring to N3485, but here, I learned something new with this one: *In addition to being available via inclusion of the <iterator> header, the function templates in 24.7 are
available when any of the following headers are included: <array>, <deque>, <forward_list>, <list>,
<map>, <regex>, <set>, <string>, <unordered_map>, <unordered_set>, and <vector>.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard *allows* any standard header to include an arbitrary number of other standard headers. It's almost never, however, actually required.

Just for example, it's fairly common to put implementation details in a `detail` namespace, and then pull names from there to become publicly accessible if and only if the user has included a header that needs to make them visible.

In other words, if you're using something, include the header. This is actually a pretty common source of problems. With older compilers, including one header often ended up defining a lot that that header wasn't required to define. Newer compilers tend to be more granular, so a lot of older code needs minor patching to include the proper headers before it'll work correctly. While not exactly the biggest portability problem that arises, this is sufficiently annoying that it's clearly better to avoid it when/if you can.

Even in the few places there's a documented requirement for one header to include another (or at least do the equivalent), I think it's a fairly poor idea to depend on it. First, because the `#include` lines act as a sort of documentation, and depending on indirect inclusion means anybody using them as documentation has to take all that indirection definition into account. Second, because it's easy to slip into thinking that because including one header has to define a few specific items normally defined in another header that it will automatically define everything in that header, which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Ooh... I totally didn't realize namespace inclusion is a possibility and it could cause problems. +1 This is perfect the kind of answer I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either the standard provides a guarantee or it does not. If it does not, then you have no guarantee. Your "implies the inclusion" argument fails because the compiler is not required to include any more of the class that it needs, and clearly anything you do with the class specifically is more than is needed.

Comment: Right, but `std::vector` is by definition *required* to use certain particular members of `std::allocator`, right? Doesn't that imply I can rely on those members of `std::allocator` being fully usable through the inclusion of `vector`?

Comment: @Mehrdad - in practice, the analysis you'd have to go through to figure out whether you can skip a particular header is far more work than simply including the appropriate header.